# Deriving flux expression for endpoints of an interval for a one dimensional fluid

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

How do I derive the following identity? I'm following a math proof on the Kuramoto model and the following identity is stated:

$$
\partial_t \int_\psi^{\psi+\delta\psi} p(\psi'|\omega)d\psi'=p(\psi|\omega)\dot{\psi}(\psi)-p(\psi+\delta\psi|\omega)\dot{\psi}(\psi+\delta\psi)
$$

where $p(\psi|\omega)$ is some unknown probability distribution with normalization $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}p(\psi|\omega)d\psi=1$ and

$$\dot{\psi}(\psi) = (\omega-\Omega) - KR\sin\psi$$

with $K,R,\omega,\Omega$ constants, is the equation of motion for $\psi$.

The two terms in the RHS represent the fluxes of probability into and out of the control interval $[\psi, \psi+\delta\psi]$, respectively.

I don't know how to derive this seemingly obvious statement (since it is taken for granted in the proof I'm following). What I have done is move the partial time derivative inside the integral, apply the chain rule and integrate by parts as the following:

$$
\int_\psi^{\psi+\delta\psi}\partial_t [p(\psi'|\omega)]d\psi' = \int_\psi^{\psi+\delta\psi} \dot{\psi}(\psi') \partial_{\psi'} [p(\psi'|\omega)]d\psi'
$$

assigning $u=\dot{\psi}(\psi')$ and $v'=\partial_{\psi}[p(\psi'|\omega)]$ and using

$$\int_a^buv'dx = uv|_a^b - \int_a^b u'vdx$$

I get:

$$
\partial_t \int_\psi^{\psi+\delta\psi} p(\psi'|\omega)d\psi'=p(\psi'|\omega)\dot{\psi}(\psi')|_{\psi}^{\psi+\delta\psi} - \int_{\psi}^{\psi+\delta\psi}(-KR\cos\psi')p(\psi'|\omega)d\psi'
$$

If the second term on the RHS is zero then I get the original identity, but I don't see any reason why this integral should be zero, fundamentally or particularly to the Kuramoto model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the time derivative inside the integral is actually a mistake, and also I think there is a sign error in the original proof. So I think the correct answer goes like this:

$$
\partial_t \int_\psi^{\psi+\delta\psi} p(\psi'|\omega)d\psi'=\partial_t \left[ P(\psi+\delta\psi|\omega)-P(\psi|\omega) \right]
$$

where $P$ is the anti-derivative of $p$. Using the chain rule we get
$$
\partial_t [P(\psi)] = \frac{\partial P(\psi)}{\partial \psi}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}
$$
and thus:

$$
\partial_t \left[ P(\psi+\delta\psi|\omega)-P(\psi|\omega) \right]=\frac{\partial P(\psi+\delta\psi|\omega)}{\partial(\psi+\delta\psi)}\frac{\partial(\psi+\delta\psi)}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial P(\psi|\omega)}{\partial\psi}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}\\
=p(\psi+\delta\psi|\omega)\dot{\psi}(\psi+\delta\psi) - p(\psi|\omega)\dot{\psi}(\psi)
$$

which is the sought expression but with opposite sign.